# How to use search_analyzer with no normalization factors?

Tags: elasticsearch

- I want to use `search_analyzer` while disabling normalization factors.
- I'm using elasticsearch:7.6.2

I configured my index:

```
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "my_analyzer": {
                        "type": "custom",
                        "tokenizer": "standard",
                        "norms": "false",

                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "content": {"type": "text",
                            "search_analyzer": "my_analyzer",
                            "analyzer": "standard"},
            }
        }
```

but is seems that it is using the normalization factors in searching time.

I have 3 documents in my index:

1. michael jordan and scottie pippen - NBA is a professional basketball league in North America.
2. michael jordan and scottie pippen - National Basketball Association
3. michael jordan and scottie pippen

I searched for `michael jordan and scottie pippen`:

```
"query": {
            "bool": {
                "must":
                    [{
                        "query_string": {
                            "default_field": "content",
                            "query":  "michael jordan and scottie pippen"
                            }
                    }]
            }
        }
```

And I expected to get 3 results with same score, but I got 3 results with a different scores.

How can I ignore normalization factors in search time ?

Comment: Please point me to the doc where `norms` can be defined at analyzer setting level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `norms` are defined at the field level and not at the analyzer level, can you try disabling `norms` on your `content` field, you can do it runtime as well as mentioned in [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/norms.html) and see you are getting expected results.